# Присваивание ссылке класса при прокрутке страницы и появлении в поле зрении якоря, на который она ссылается

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Задача стоит следующая: есть подобие плавающего меню, со ссылками на якоря в тексте, при прокрутке страницы, когда очередной якорь появляется в поле зрения (допустим 100px от нижней части окна), должен присваиваться класс (active) соответствующей этому якорю ссылке. 
ниже для наглядности вставил код, а вот ссылочка на заготовку: https://jsfiddle.net/UeML6/310/

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#one">Один</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#two">Два</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#three">Новости</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
            <a class="oneyak" name="one"> Один</a>
    текст текст текст
            </p>
                <p>
            <a class="twoyak" name="two">Два</a>
    текст текст текст
        </p>
                <p>
            <a class="threeyak" name="three">Три</a>
    текст текст текст
        </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста ваш вариант решения проблемы и в чем конкретно возникли вопросы, полностью писать за вас код вряд ли кто-то будет

Answer (score 2):

Технология, которая вам нужна называется scrollspy. Как вариант не городить свой велосипед, а воспользоваться готовым решением. В таких CSS фрэймворках как bootstrap, materializecss она уже встроена. 
Если вы не используете фрэймворков, то можете использовать библиотеку: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Answer (score 1):

Можно отследить видимость ссылок через событие scroll window, например как-то так:

```
<script>

var $win = $(window);
var $marksname = ["one","two","three"]; //имена ссылок с якорями
var $markstop = []; //под положение на странице для якорей
var $marks = []; //сами якоря
var $marksclass = []; //изначальный класс
var $links = $(document.getElementsByTagName("a")); //берем все ссылки

for (var $i = 0; $i < $links.length; $i++) { //ищем якоря
 for (var $y = 0; $y < $marksname.length; $y++) //ищем наши якоря
  if ($links[$i].name == $marksname[$y]) { //если эта ссылка с нашим именем
   $markstop[$markstop.length] = $links[$i].offsetTop; //добавляем положение по высоте
   $marks[$marks.length] = $links[$i]; //сама ссылка (для изменения)
   $marksclass[$marksclass.length] = $links[$i].className; //запоминаем ее начальный класс
  }
}

$win.scroll(function() { //обработчик события при прокрутки страницы
 for (var $i = 0; $i < $markstop.length; $i++) { //перебираем все наши якоря по высоте
  if (($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() - 100 >= $markstop[$i]) && ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() < $markstop[$i] + $win.height() - 100)) { //смотрим видать ли нашу ссылку на экране
   if ($marks[$i].className != "active") $marks[$i].className = "active"; //меняем класс
  }
  else //если ссылку не видать на экране
   if ($marks[$i].className == "active") $marks[$i].className = $marksclass[$i]; //возвращаем начальный класс
  }
});

</script>
```